# Python variable scope across files

Tags: python

I am trying to get a simple (temporary) way of sharing some settings between several python modules working. Currently I am experimenting with the following code:

A.py:

```
from B import *
from C import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
    dummy = "def"
    print "Second"
    Test()
```

B.py:

```
from C import *

def Test():
    print dummy
```

C.py:

```
dummy = "abc"
```

When I run this with 'python A.py' I would expect this to print as its output the following:

```
abc
Second
def
```

However, the result I actually get is:

```
abc
Second
abc
```

This shows that the assignment to the variable dummy does not show up in the B module. Why is that?